# How to complete overdue tasks in SharePoint 2013

Tags: task-list

I want to know if there is a way to complete overdue(late) tasks in SharePoint 2013 but without using the "Mark as Complete" check box.Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create List Workflow to auto complete expired tasks:

```
Loop With Condition: DueDate > Today
   Pause for Duration: Interval 
Then Set Field: TaskStatus = Completed
```

SharePoint Designer Workflow

[image]

### How to update item in another list using Update List Item action

- Select `Update List Item` action
- Select List and Field and set field value

[image]

Comment: hey thanks man! I have one more question, Is it possible to set the value of a field in another list with designer workflow working on a separated list...

Comment: For Example: i have listA on which i am running the designer workflow and now i want to set a field in listB from this workflow. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, [Update List Item] or [Call HTTP Web Service] actions are intended for that purpose

Comment: can you show me which action to use in designer to do that?

Comment: the answer has been updated